# Using a custom UITableViewCell with different custom classes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a xib file named MyCell.xib with a custom UITableView cell and MyCell.swift where I have outlets and code that sets constraints.

Now I want to use that xib file in a different UITableView and have MyNewCell.swift inherited from MyCell.swift in order to override the code that set constraints. However, I don't know how to do it because in my xib I can only specify one class as a custom class for my cell. And when I get a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath I get an object of type MyCell not MyNewCell.

Comment: If you want to load the cell from a xib, you are going to need a new xib for the subclass, although I'm guessing you're avoiding that because of the unnecessary duplication it would involve. Without seeing code it's hard to offer a real answer. Maybe you could go with a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) approach - have a factory object that has a reference to the TV (so can dequeue a vanilla base cell, then configure it based on some parameter(s). Then call the factory method appropriate in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`